# Distinction between [resource-recommendations] and [specific-reference] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, resource-recommendation

[Resource reference for Induction due to Time Varying Magnetic Fields (TVMF)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/573921/)

I asked the above question with the tag [specific-reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-reference). The purpose behind doing so is that the tag page suggests

*if one has a specific topic to ask, by using this tag he or she shall get it*

-as per orders issued by physics community of Stack Exchange.

**My question is**, was my [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/573921/) not a [specific-reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-reference) request more than a [resource-recommendation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendation) which asks for more *data*? And why was it so?

Also, I request to describe the tags more appropriately possible with more examples.

> A resource recommendation question is one that asks for a resource (which can be a book, website, or other resource) to learn a topic from. It should have the resource-recommendation tag.

> This is not the same as a specific-reference question, which asks for a specific paper in which a derivation or concept is explained.

Mine was asking to *show* a specific concept so should have been the latter. But thinking about it now, it also asks for experimental evidences, lecture notes etc. So I am just confused about which of the tags to be used.

Comment: What about the description of the tags is not clear?

Comment: Echoing @BioPhysicist: What about the  tag wiki descriptions [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/resource-recommendations/info) & [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-reference/info) are not clear?

Comment: @BioPhysicist addressed

Comment: @Qmechanic addressed in question, also removed my comments

Comment: @Qmechanic I don't think they are always that clear: What category would [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/625936/about-the-fact-that-almost-all-quantum-states-are-entangled) fall into? It asks a very specific question (not: "Where can I learn this topic?", and answers are certainly not expected to discuss contents of sources), but it also doesn't ask for the specific paper where this was first stated (which might well not exist, in the sense of this always being a "folk" statement).

Comment: @Norbert Schuch: q 625936 seems to be closer to res. recom. than to spec. ref., cf. below answer by Urb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing a specific topic with a specific reference. Your question is about a very specific **topic**, but it asks for **any reference** that covers the topic in detail, i.e. any book, any paper, etc. The list of possible answers is not closed, so it should be tagged as a [resource-recommendation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendation) question.